# Need to call a method in another class with timer and once done to return control to the main partial class (user control)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, user-controls

Please go through the following code which is an oversimplification of the code I have.
I need to know how once the timer is elapsed, how to return control to the main user control class, preferably to the same case within the switch statement.

```
public partial class ucClass : UserControl
{
    int A;
    Label labelTimer = new Label();
    
    sec secObj = new sec();
    
    public execute()
    {
        switch(A)
        {
        case 1:
            secObj.initiate(labelTimer, 10);
            break:
        case 2:
        ......
        }
    }
    
}
class sec
{
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    
    private Label labelTimer = new Label();
    private int expectedCount = 0;
    private int actualCount = 0;
    
    public void initiate(Label labelTimer, int count)
    {
        this.expectedCount = count;
        this.labelTimer = labelTimer;
        this.timer.Interval = 1000;
        startTimer();
    }
    
    private void startTimer()
    {
        this.timer.Start();
        this.timer.Tick += this.timerElapsed;
    }
    
    private void timerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer.Dispose();
        if(expectedCount > actualCount)
        {
            this.actualCount += 1;
            this.labelTimer.Text = this.actualCount.ToString();
            this.startTimer();
        }
        else
        {
            //this is where I need to notify the main class that timer has expired and go to case 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide more information about your attempt? What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @John After the timer in "sec" class has elapsed, I need to return the control to the user-control class

Comment: I mean, control is returned to the user control immediately after `initiate` completes. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @John, I was able to do all these in the user control class itself.  But due to various reasons, I am attempting to do with a separate "sec" class.  I call "initiate" method in "sec" class in case 1 of execute method of user control class.  After timer completes, I have to run case 2 of execute method of user control class.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes. It's not at all clear what you mean when you say you want to "return control" to the user control. What is "control" in this respect? You're not disabling anything on the user control, and the code within initiate isn't blocking until the timer is finished, so if control means "the execution flow of the main thread" then that automatically returns to the user control after `initiate()` is completed.

Comment: @John, yes your definition of control is correct.  The thing is it returns to the user control after Initiate() is completed, but also it executes other commands before all code written under initiate() is completed.  I want to wait in the main user control class (without blocking) till all code in Initiate() completes and then return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the behavior that you want with events:

```cs
public partial class ucClass : UserControl
{
    int A;
    Label labelTimer = new Label();
    
    sec secObj = new sec();

    public ucClass()
    {
        // Listen to event from timer
        secObj.TimerExpired += (sender, args) =>
        {
             A = args.Count;
             execute();
        };
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        switch(A)
        {
            case 1:
                secObj.initiate(labelTimer, 10);
                break:
            case 2:
                ......
        }
    }
    
}

class sec
{
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public event EventHandler<TimerExpiredEventArgs> TimerExpired;
    
    private Label labelTimer = new Label();
    private int expectedCount = 0;
    private int actualCount = 0;
    
    public void initiate(Label labelTimer, int count)
    {
        this.expectedCount = count;
        this.labelTimer = labelTimer;
        this.timer.Interval = 1000;
        startTimer();
    }
    
    private void startTimer()
    {
        this.timer.Start();
        this.timer.Tick += this.timerElapsed;
    }
    
    private void timerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer.Dispose();
        if(expectedCount > actualCount)
        {
            this.actualCount += 1;
            this.labelTimer.Text = this.actualCount.ToString();
            this.startTimer();
        }
        else
        {
            // Send event with count
            TimerExpired?.Invoke(this, new TimerExpiredEventArgs
            {
                Count = actualCount
            });

        }
    }
}

public class TimerExpiredEventArgs
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I would recommend looking into the following;

- The MVVM pattern

  - This will allow you to seperate the UI logic (passing around labels etc) and the control logic (timers etc).
- Reactive Extensions (https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)

  - This would allow for a very simple timer:

  ```cs
    Observable
       .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
       .Subscribe(count => {
          labelTimer.Text = count.ToString();
          if (count > actualCount) {
            A = args.Count;
            execute();
          }
       });
  ```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to implement from your answer, and I am getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Action)' error.  Googling it, I received code related to WPF application.  I am using Winforms.  Could you help me how to proceed?

Comment: Okay, I saw you are using the forms timer, so you can forgo the dispatcher calls. I'll update the answer.